# Generate react.fragment for multiple items via function

Tags: reactjs

In the midst of me cleaning out a massive react render statement, I've been breaking some things out into helper functions. Here's a portion of what I have in a helper function:

```
// This looks ugly
return (
  <>
    {label}
    {getDropdown(
      daysOfWeek,
      handleDaysOfWeekChange,
      daysOfWeekLabel,
      options.dayOfWeek,
      isMultiSelectEnabled
    )}
  </>
);
```

The particulars of the getDropdown function don't matter. Label is a react component (and is defined as a variable since it's used elsewhere as well), and getDropdown returns a react component.

For some reason this just looks ugly to me, we start with a react.fragment so that we can have multiple javascript code snippets, but in turn each javascript snippet is either a variable which equals a react component, or a function which is computed at runtime to a react component. *So we're really going from the react paradigm to javascript paradigm and then back to react.*

I'd like something like this which is all javascript paradigm:

```
// invalid code!
return React.fillFragment(
  label,
  getDropdown(
    daysOfMonth,
    handleDaysOfMonthChange,
    daysOfMonthLabel,
    options.dayOfMonth,
    isMultiSelectEnabled
  ),
);
```

Returning an array just gives key errors, and we wouldn't want to overload this since there are other areas where we would want to return an array without a fragment.

The next best solution that I can think of is to simply treat these two as actual components, which would be the all react paradigm:

```
// Works, but still feels verbose
return (
  <>
    <Label/>
    <GetDropDown
      value={daysOfMonth}
      onChange={handleDaysOfMonthChange}
      defaultLabel={daysOfMonthLabel}
      listOptions={options.dayOfMonth}
      isMultiSelect={isMultiSelectEnabled}
    />
  </>
);
```

And this does work, but it feels a little overkill and isn't the most succinct for a couple one time use functions. (for example label is only used here and one other spot.)

I'm wondering is there something built in that I haven't been able to find, or is there a little trick here that I've never come across? Or maybe I'm being too picky

Answer (score 0):

You last snippet look best to me.

If `getDropdown` returns a React component, then it is probably best for it to be a React component.

If you dislike `<></>` fragment syntax, you can put `<Fragment></Fragment>` instead.

If you want no fragment at all, you either have to inline your components `Label` and `GetDropDown` into their parent component. Or put `Label` into `GetDropDown` (`GetDropDown` should be renamed `Dropdown` by the way).

I don't know the content of `GetDropDown` and `Label`, but if there is nothing more than in a `select` and `label`, you may not want to create a React component.

If you have custom style applied to the `label` and `select` element, you can either add a global style sheet, or -preferred solution- use a css-in-js library like `styled-components`:

```
// Label is a component, with the custom style you define here.
const Label = styled.label`
  color: grey;
`;
```

Adding small components like that, has negligible performance cost.